# FedEx API - Label (PDF and ZPL)

Tags: python, wsdl, fedex

I try to use this lib https://python-fedex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

In shipment request i have this:

```
shipment.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.LabelFormatType = 'COMMON2D'
shipment.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.ImageType = *format*
shipment.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.LabelStockType = 'STOCK_4X6'
```

To request shipping label in PDF, ZPLII, ELP2 or other format. But I can give only one format.

But what if I need PDF and ZPLII in same time. How I can do this?

This **safo-bora** code for examl to see what I mean:
https://gist.github.com/safo-bora/2c6a67ad1299fc2a83d74fb1759f8a41